# Pages redirect to homepage when user logs out from them

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm new to Joomla, and I am having this strange issue that I can't find any help on, and I have no idea how to go about even debugging it.

Basically, whenever a user **logs out** on a page, that page from there on out redirects to the homepage.  If I clear my cookies, everything goes back to normal, and the page is accessible again.

This doesn't happen in Chrome, just Firefox and IE.  I'm using Joomla 2.5.

I've looked at the debug console but I didn't find any stand out clues.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Module Manager, open the Login module, and in the parameters section, there are 2 fields to choose the redirection after logging in and out.

Comment: The problem is that after log out, that page is inaccessible after logging out.  So, if you log out on the "About Us" page, every time any other user tries to access "About Us" it redirects them to the homepage.

Comment: have you set the permissions fr the "About Us" page to public?

Comment: Yes all of the permissions are properly set.  The problem does not exist until a user logs out.

Comment: I assume you haven't touched any of the core Joomla files, however try downloading the Joomla 2.5 package, then uploading the "includes" and "libraries" folders and overwriting the current ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with joomla 2.5 on Firefox, but not on Chrome. Problem would reset when I cleared the cache, until I did a logout again. Then the home page content would get written into my cache for the page I had been on for registered users only, when I logged out.

I fixed it when I set the Login module to explicitly take the user to the home page, rather than leaving the setting at default. Then it worked correctly for both browsers, and the home page content no longer got cached as the registered users only page.

Set the logout behavior in Extensions: Module Manager: Module Login: Basic Options

Hope it fixes your problem also!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is over a year old, but I just worked through the same issue. Hopefully my answer can still be useful to someone. The solution was to disable a plugin called "System - Logout" and clear the browser's cache afterwords. This fixed both the issue of not being able to get back to the page after logout, and an issue where the "Logout Redirection Page" parameter set in the login module was being ignored.